# Schlage passage lockset, unable to remove either handle

Tags: doors

I have what I believe is a Schlage passage lock-set that I am unable to uninstall.

I tried the sharp pin in the hole trick (*actually I used a small drift pin*). I am attaching pictures. Please notice there are 2 holes in each lever. I applied the drift pin to all 4 holes, even while turning the handle. Nothing works.

I called the Schlage company and spoke to a friendly and polite man. I sent him pictures of the lock and he replied with a totally useless canned installation instruction (*So much for the manufacturer being the expert*).

Any ideas on  how to remove this doorknob would be apriciated. (*If not my next trick will be a Sawzall*).

[![Inside view[image].

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to pry off the round cover ? The one on the inside of the door, as the screws that hold the doorknob are on that side.  A small thin flat blade screw driver should work.

Comment: Thanks Alaska man. No I have not....at least not yet. I thought I'd try the easy way first. This is on a door to one of my customers so once I start the job I must finish it that day. I just want to make sure I can do that before I tear into it.

Comment: There should be a tiny slot that you can get a prying tool into. Once the round escutcheon is off you can remove the set without having to remove the handle from the rest of the mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

The round escutcheon should just be pressed on. There should be a very small slot that you can get a thin, small, flat blade screwdriver into and pry it off. (*away from the door*).

Once the escutcheon is off, the two screws that hold the mechanism together will be accessible and you can UN-install the doorknob.

Comment: Thanks Alaska Man, I'll try that and report back in a couple of days.

Comment: Alaska Man, You were correct in how it came apart. Thanks a lot!!